# XSLT Parsing multiple nested children with tag id help

Tags: xml, xslt, global-variables, children, nested-attributes

I have the following xml that I need parsed into name/value pairs using XSLT. No matter what I try, I cannot get it right. I know you cannot have a global "counter" to keep track of the batches, but I have tried recursive templates, calling a java helper class, position(), count, you name it...I am stuck.

The "batches" need to be numbered the same for all the children elements included.

Here is my XML snippet:

```
<extendedDataElements name="Feed" type="string">
<children name="fileId" type="string">
      <values>TXT123</values>
</children>

<children name="processedTime" type="dateTime">
      <values>2011-07-08T20:15:38</values>
</children>

<children name="batch" type="string">
    <values>0000001</values>
    <children name="statusCode" type="string">
        <values>new</values>
    </children>
</children> 

<children name="batch" type="string">
    <values>0000002</values>
    <children name="statusCode" type="string">
        <values>start</values>
    </children>       
</children>

<children name="batch" type="string">
    <values>0000003</values>
    <children name="statusCode" type="string">
        <values>new</values>
     </children>
</children>

<children name="count" type="long">
      <values>26</values>
</children>
<children name="value" type="double">
      <values>83171.650</values>
</children>
</extendedDataElements>
```

Here is what I need:

```
fileID=TXT123, processedTime=2011-07-08T20:15:38, batch1=0000001, statusCode1=new, batch2=0000002, statusCode2=start, batch3=0000003, statusCode3=new, count=26, value=83171.650
```

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a short and easy solution using templates, pattern matching and the `<xsl:number>` instruction. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="children">
         <xsl:if test="not(position()=1)">, </xsl:if>
         <xsl:value-of select="concat(@name,'=',values)"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="children[@name='batch']">
  <xsl:variable name="vNum">
   <xsl:number count="children[@name='batch']" level="single"/>
  </xsl:variable>

         <xsl:if test="not(position()=1)">, </xsl:if>
  <xsl:value-of select="concat('batch', $vNum, '=', values)"/>

  <xsl:apply-templates select="children"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
  "children[@name='batch']/children">

  <xsl:variable name="vNum">
    <xsl:for-each select="..">
      <xsl:number count="children[@name='batch']" level="single"/>
     </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:value-of select=
    "concat(', ',@name,$vNum,'=',values)"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<extendedDataElements name="Feed" type="string">
    <children name="fileId" type="string">
        <values>TXT123</values>
    </children>
    <children name="processedTime" type="dateTime">
        <values>2011-07-08T20:15:38</values>
    </children>
    <children name="batch" type="string">
        <values>0000001</values>
        <children name="statusCode" type="string">
            <values>new</values>
        </children>
    </children>
    <children name="batch" type="string">
        <values>0000002</values>
        <children name="statusCode" type="string">
            <values>start</values>
        </children>
    </children>
    <children name="batch" type="string">
        <values>0000003</values>
        <children name="statusCode" type="string">
            <values>new</values>
        </children>
    </children>
    <children name="count" type="long">
        <values>26</values>
    </children>
    <children name="value" type="double">
        <values>83171.650</values>
    </children>
</extendedDataElements>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
fileId=TXT123, processedTime=2011-07-08T20:15:38, batch1=0000001, statusCode1=new, batch2=0000002, statusCode2=start, batch3=0000003, statusCode3=new, count=26, value=83171.650
```

**Explanation**: Good use of the following essential XSLT features:

1. **Templates and pattern matching**.
2. **[`<xsl:number>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#number)**

Answer (score 1):

You can use the XPath `number()` function to rename the batch pairs. For example, XPath `number('0000001')=1`. These, together with XPath `concat()`, will help you to assemble the required batch pairs.

To handle the comma, I've opted for template mode technique, but you can handle it as you prefer.

[XSLT 1.0]

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="children"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="children[not(@name='batch')]">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(
            @name,'=',values)"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="self::*[following-sibling::*]" 
            mode="comma"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="children[@name='batch']">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(
            @name,number(values),'=',values,', ',
            children/@name,number(values),'=',children/values)"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="self::*[following-sibling::*]" 
            mode="comma"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="children" mode="comma">
        <xsl:value-of select="', '"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

with output:

```
fileId=TXT123, processedTime=2011-07-08T20:15:38, batch1=0000001, statusCode1=new, batch2=0000002, statusCode2=start, batch3=0000003, statusCode3=new, count=26, value=83171.650
```

Comment: +1 Didnt seem to work exactly for my xml, but I learned alot from your template. Thank you!